# Creating a small Windows Application that control windows size by java?

Tags: java

**The Idea:**
A small tool/program that change the size of any window folder/application is currently open.
If I have a Maximized Safari Window opened, when I click a button in the tool it reduces the size by 20%.
If I click the button again, it reduces to half size, and so on.

**My question is:**
 Could you make such a program using Java Langauge? if the answer is yes, could you please lead me to the correct way of how to do it? is there such a windows API for java? and if no, please explain to me why? I'm still an on-going Java learner obviously, so be easy on me Stacks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is not the best tool for this as to do this well, you need a tool that can get very close to the operating system, and Java is just the opposite -- it was built to be as operating system agnostic as possible. Don't get me wrong, this is do-able with Java, but in order to get Java to do this, you'll have to bend and stretch it via JNA (which is how I'd do it if it were me) and/or JNI in ways that are a little tricky to do, and often make your program non-portable. Better to use an OS-specific utility language such as AutoIt is a Windows environment or perhaps C/C++.

Comment: thought so, that's why I asked if there is such a way, looks like there actually is, complicated tho :S. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what is JNI, but I'm going to check it.

Comment: Actually it's not terribly complicated, and it is quite do-able, but even so, there are other tools that are built for doing just this, so I prefer to use those.

Comment: @iMohammad:if you're going to check out JNI, also check out JNA which was built on JNI.

Comment: Let me finish this lecture and I'll do some reading :) . Thanks @Hovercraft. Much Appreciated.